# Неправильно переключаются checkbox-ы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть два чекбокса. Один сразу отмечен, второй нет.
Нужно когда кликаешь по чекбоксу оба изменил состояния checked на обратное тому, что сейчас есть.
Если кликать только по одному чекбоксу то все ок. Но если после кликнуть по другому - все ломается.

В любом случае должен быть хоть один чекбокс отмечен

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {

  if( !$(this).is(':checked')) {

    $('input:checkbox').not(this).eq(0).attr('checked', 'checked');

    $(this).eq(0).removeAttr('checked');

  } else {

    $('input:checkbox').not(this).eq(0).removeAttr('checked');

    $(this).eq(0).attr('checked', 'checked');

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="recruiter-switch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="recruiter" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="company-switch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="company">
```

Comment: По-помему сейчас все работает так, как нужно.

Comment: Покликайте несколько раз по одному и тому же чекбоксу. А потом по другому. В любом случае должен быть хоть один чекбокс отмечен

Comment: А чем же вам `radio button`'ы не угодили? Они как раз для этого и предназначены.

Comment: @Cheg идея в том, что я их стилизирую под такой элемент как switch. Такой переключатель off/on.
Если проинспектировать чекбоксы, то JS работает и в самом html-е состояние checked меняется, но куда-то галка пропадает после нескольких кликов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {

  if( !$(this).is(':checked')) {

    $('input:checkbox').not(this).eq(0).prop('checked', true);

  } else {

    $('input:checkbox').not(this).eq(0).prop('checked', false);

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="recruiter-switch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="recruiter" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="company-switch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="company">
```

Не имеет смысла менять флаг для текущего, он автоматом делается

Comment: Да, работает. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Вот так покороче

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function () {
    var a = !$(this).is(':checked');
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).eq(0).prop('checked', a);
})
```